# Self-signed certificate not work inside docker for communication among containers

Tags: docker, docker-container, self-signed-certificate

I have a docker-compose in which minio, minio/kes and vault talk together. Both minio/kes and vault need TLS, and I used self-signed method with IP address to create certificate for them.
I use this command to generate certificate:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 7300 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -out server.cert \
       -subj "/C=/ST=/L=/O=/CN=localhost" -addext "subjectAltName = IP:127.0.0.1"
```

here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2021-02-01T22-56-52Z
    container_name: minio
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /home/zahra/docker/minio/data:/data
      - /home/zahra/docker/kes/certs:/root/.minio/kes/certs
    ports:
      - "9003:9000"
    expose:
      - "9003"
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: minio
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: minio123
      MINIO_KMS_KES_ENDPOINT: https://minio-kes:7373
      MINIO_KMS_KES_CERT_FILE: /root/.minio/kes/certs/client.cert
      MINIO_KMS_KES_KEY_FILE: /root/.minio/kes/certs/client.key
      MINIO_KMS_KES_CA_PATH: /root/.minio/kes/certs/server.cert
      MINIO_KMS_KES_KEY_NAME: test-key
      MINIO_KMS_AUTO_ENCRYPTION: 1
    command: server /data
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 3    
    networks: 
      - minio-network 
    
  minio-kes:
    image: minio/kes:v0.19.2
    container_name: minio-kes
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /home/zahra/docker/kes/certs:/root/.kes/certs    
      - /home/zahra/docker/kes/config:/root/.kes/config
      - /home/zahra/docker/vault/certs:/root/.kes/vault/certs
    environment:
      - KES_SERVER=https://minio-vault:7373
      - KES_CLIENT_KEY=/root/.kes/certs/client.key
      - KES_CLIENT_CERT=/root/.kes/certs/client.cert      
    ports:
      - "7373:7373"
    command: server --config=/root/.kes/config/config.yaml --auth=off 
    expose:
      - "7373"
    networks:  
      - minio-network 
    depends_on:
      - minio-vault    
      
  minio-vault:
        image: vault:latest
        container_name: minio-vault
        ports:
          - "8200:8200"
        volumes:
          - /home/zahra/docker/vault/file:/vault/file
          - /home/zahra/docker/vault/config:/vault/config
          - /home/zahra/docker/vault/certs:/vault/certs
          - /home/zahra/docker/vault/policy:/vault/policy
        environment:
          - VAULT_ADDR=https://127.0.0.1:8200
          - VAULT_SKIP_VERIFY=true
          - VAULT_TOKEN=MY-TOKEN
        cap_add:
          - IPC_LOCK
        entrypoint: vault server -config=/vault/config/config.json
        networks:  
          - minio-network  
     
networks:
  minio-network:
    driver: bridge
```

My problem is that inside docker, I have to use the container-name instead of the IP address of my services, so it gives me the following error:
x509 :certificate is not valid for any names but wanted to match minio-kes
or
x509 :certificate is not valid for any names but wanted to match minio-vault.

minio-kes and minio-kes are my container names.

I tried to replace the common name (CN) while generating the certificate with the name of my container, but again it didn’t work. For example:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 7300 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -out server.cert \
       -subj "/C=/ST=/L=/O=/CN=minio-kes" -addext "subjectAltName = IP:127.0.0.1"
```

I don’t know how I should generate certificate in order to work inside docker.

Comment: I'm not sure what your questions is - but did you try to add the missing server names to the certificate? Like `-addext "subjectAltName = DNS:minio-kes"`. Also see [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/183973/134095) for details.

Comment: Maybe this article can help you https://medium.com/@mdesmet_7096/zero-trust-data-access-using-minio-and-trino-6140f78f410f. If you find the solution for your problem, can you please share it in github?

Comment: The reply from @not2savvy solved my problem. I wrote here a couple of days a go, but I don't know why my comment was deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the domain names to connect, you must add these domain names to the certificate. This can be achieved by adding `-addext "subjectAltName = DNS:minio-kes"` to the openssl command.

A certificate can be made valid for multiple domain names. Just add the parameter multiple times in order to add multiple domain names to the certificate.

Also [see this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/183973/134095) for further details.